# Table with border-collapse works differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-tables

Please test [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twa368ec/) in Chrome and Firefox. They work differently.
In Firefox background is at right position (top enough from the text). But in Chrome background lies below the expected level.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429195/border-collapse-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox). Bu it does not work for me. I cannot set my table rows to `display: block`

And I cannot set top padding to `td`s. Because there has an element with absolute position inside `td`s which takes full height of `td`.

The ultimate goal is set background position to top and maintain a distance between each vertical `td`.

Thanks for helping.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
}
tr {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/10x5/000/fff.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}
td {
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>tr1 td1</td>
   <td>tr1 td2</td>
   <td>tr1 td3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>tr2 td1</td>
   <td>tr2 td2</td>
   <td>tr2 td3</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the [`background-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin) property is set to `padding-box`.

It seems the problem is due to discrepancies about determining the padding box in tabular layouts.

The solution is setting the property to `border-box`:

```css
tr {
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4wQ9.jpg) repeat-x left top;
  background-origin: border-box;
}
td {
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>tr1 td1</td>
      <td>tr1 td2</td>
      <td>tr1 td3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tr2 td1</td>
      <td>tr2 td2</td>
      <td>tr2 td3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```